# Unable to open xml file in Django python using open()

Tags: python, django

I am trying to open and .xml file using open() and then convert it into dictionary. I am using it in django application
File is also located at correct location..

Problem is "\" is getting replaced with "\\" and file extension ".xml" with ".xmlf"
 and no such file directory is error as in snapshot[image]

Filepath is changing can be seen into image.

code for reading file is 
[image]

how to resolve the error in django server

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and replace image with code.

Comment: also please show how did you check the file exists in the path?

Comment: I see that in your code you've written "abc.xmlf". And you are saying that XML is getting replaced with XMLF. And try to do this os.path. What's the BASE_DIR?

Comment: pass the path like this - r"path". Add r as a prefix to path, which will make it to the raw path.

Comment: Thanks @yash but path is given in variable filepath and is passed to open() function of python to open file.   If I print filepath I am getting "C:\Users\sumitcha\environments\django\project1\abc.xml" properly but when tried to open(filepath)  "'C:\\Users\\sumitcha\\environments\\django\\project1\\abc.xml'"   how to deal with this .

Comment: In file path you passed the wrong file i.e., "abc.xmlf". It should be "abc.xml".